# How to count a specific text across multiple sheets matching with column headers?

Tags: windows

I don't know how to explain it. I have 8 sheets where 1st one is for SUMMARY, others sheets are with same column header where item names are mentioned. I need to extract item status according to the columns headers in SUMMARY sheet.

[image]

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: So you just need a given value from each sheet to show on the summary sheet? What have you tried so far?